# How to get my app link on Amazon appstore before publishing?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I'm about to finish building my app and I want to publish it on Amazon appstore. On Google Play I can know how my app link will be before publishing it, it's all set like this

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="My app package name"
```

But how can I do the same on Amazon?, I need to create a button to share the app link on the store.
And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=<your app package name>
```

Documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/reports-promo/deeplink-to-the-amazon-client.html